# How do I say “I would like to attend [this event]”

Tags: traduction, y

I’m trying to ask a question on a post about an event. I want to start by saying “I’d like to come/attend but…”

Can I just say

> « Je voudrais venir mais… »

or is it better to say something more like:

> « Je voudrais y venir mais… »
> Blockquote

or

> « je voudrais venir à cet événement mais… »

I don’t quite understand when I can just imply something and when I have to be more specific!

Comment: To me (French speaker from France). 1 is quite OK. 2 is bizarre (we would say « Je voudrais y aller mais… ». Same thing in 3: I would say aller instead of venir.

Comment: So for 2, using “venir” is the bizarre part, but using “y” would be correct, right? Thank you for your help!

Comment: The verb aller is the one that can't be used alone: You can't say "Je vais" by itself, you have to say "J'y vais." Venir doesn't have this rule, you can just say "Je viens." So it's the same thing in your sentence: Je voudrais venir but Je voudrais y aller.

Comment: "to attend an event " is formal in English. The French here is therefore assister.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between "vouloir" and "aimer"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32805/difference-between-vouloir-and-aimer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Je voudrais venir mais...* is fine.

Here are alternatives, closer to "I'd like to":

> *J'aimerais bien venir mais...*
> *J'aimerais bien y aller mais...*
> *J'aimerais bien y assister mais...*